# Slider next button issue

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a simple slider to which I want to add "next" button which would take me to the next slide. What I also need to do is go back to the first slide once the user reaches last slide.

What I have so far is:

```
jQuery('#next_test').click(function(e){

showSlide = 0;

slidesLength = jQuery('#page-slider .slides-image img').length;
active_slide = jQuery('#page-slider .slides-image img:first');

next = showSlide+1;
showSlide = next;


jQuery('#page-slider .slides-image img').eq(showSlide).fadeIn(700);

return false
});
```

The slider is built the way that I can show the slide by providing its number (showSlide).
So I'm trying to set the initial number to 0 which would be first slide and then, every time user clicks, it would lead him to the next slide, meaning next number. At the end it would start from the first number again.

The code above increments the number of the target slide but only once. How do I get this done? Is the foreach loop required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution required getting the active slide and its index. Then by increasing the slide index by one, the button would go to the next slide. Since the first slide has an index of 0, the conditional statement had to be created to make sure the slide index is not greater than the amount of slides and prevent it from getting to the non existing slide.

jQuery('.slides-image').click(function(e){
        var active_slide = jQuery('#page-slider .slides-image img:visible');
        var active_index = active_slide.index();
        var showSlide = 0;

```
    var slidesLength = jQuery('#page-slider .slides-image img').length;

    var showSlide = active_index+1;
    if(showSlide > slidesLength-1){
        showSlide = 0;
    }
    jQuery('#page-slider .slides-nav a').eq(showSlide).addClass('active');
    jQuery('#page-slider .slides-nav a').eq(showSlide-1).removeClass('active');
    jQuery('#page-slider .slides-image img').eq(showSlide).fadeIn(700);
    jQuery('#page-slider .slides-image img').eq(showSlide-1).hide();

return false
});
```